# Json in Php Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a doubt in json used in php to get values from mysql database.....

This is what i need

`{"results":[{"gender":"female","name":{"title":"Ms","f.........`

But i got was

`[{"id":"518","recurring":null,"from1":"","to":"","days.........`

I want the result to be printed at the first.....

And my code is

[image: My code]

```
<?php
//open connection to mysql db
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","multilogin_admin","MULTIlOGIN","HMS_multiLogin") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

//fetch table rows from mysql db
$sql = "select * from appointment";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

//create an array
$emparray = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $emparray[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($emparray);

//close the db connection
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

This is my problem!!!

Comment: Your json is the result of all of the rows in your database. If you want it in a different format, you're going to have to build out the array structure yourself before encoding it.

Comment: As @aynber mentioned, you are just fetching it from the database and pushing each row into $emparray. If you want it in any other format you will need to modify it before JSON encoding and printing it.

Comment: @SibiKandathil how to modify it i don't know about it

Comment: @aynber i have added my code can you answer this

Comment: I don't know your data structure, so I cannot. As I mentioned, the json you are getting currently is an exact row-by-row copy of your table. If you want a different data structure, you're going to have to decide how you want your data built out and write the code to do so.